# Result: [OPERATION FAILED]: MyFirstVFPage: The page you have tried to delete is currently being referenced by a page, custom link, button

Tags: salesforce

I am facing the below error in my salesforce.org.

```
Operation: Deleting Selected Metadata
Timestamp: Wed, 29 Mar 2017 19:47:33
   Result: [OPERATION FAILED]: MyFirstVFPage: The page you have tried to delete is currently being referenced by a page, custom link, button, web tab, dashboard, SoftPhone layout or custom sidebar component. Please delete the reference before deleting the page.
```

I am not sure whats going wrong and where to check it ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The message says that your Visualforce page is referenced from a button, page layout, etc. You cannot delete a page if it is used anywhere.

To find out what refers to your page, go to Setup/Build/Develop/Visualforce Pages and click on the field label for your page (MyFirstVFPage). At the top of the detail page, click the button "Where is this used?". This will display a list of all places that refer to your page.

You will need to remove the Visualforce page from anything in the list.